# About Autorun feature in Windows7

Tags: windows, autorun

I have a Autorun.inf which can work in XP and Vista, but I found Windows7 can't recognize and work with it, does Windows7 drop the autorun feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this page should be able to help you: http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3918.html